# call same function inside function react

Tags: reactjs, eslint

Hey I'm trying to see a way I can call a function inside the same function but I'm getting an ESLint error when I do 'function' this was used before it was defined.  no-use-before-define. There is a purpose I'm doing this when I call function a based on response I need to trigger 'b' if response is not satisfied then I need to call 'a' again

```
const a = () => {
  b();
}

const b = () => {
  a();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Disable the lint for that line, then, with e.g.

```
const a = () => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-use-before-define
  b();
}
```

It's just a stylistic warning.

Answer (score -1):

To have dependent functions despite `no-use-before-define`, you could use [callback functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function).

Assuming you call function `a` first - pass function `b` as an argument to function `a`, then invoke that argument there to call function `b`.

```js
const a = (functionB) => {
  functionB();
}

const b = () => {
  a();
}

a(b);
```